# Function ignoring my if condition statement

Tags: r, recursion, tree-traversal

I have a tree outlined in a data frame as:

```
       number conc knot neg pick
           1    1    0   0    1
           2    1    0   0    1
           3    1    0   0    1
           4    3  164   0    1
           5    1    0   0    1
           6    1    0   0    1
           7    3  159   1    1
           8    0    0   0    0
           9    0    0   0    0
          10    3  208   1    1
          11    3  181   1    1
          12    3    1   1    1
          13    3   95   0    1
          14    0    0   0    0
          15    0    0   0    0
```

I'm traversing the tree with a recursive function:

```
printtree <- function(number,tree) {
    if (!is.na(tree[number,5] != 0)) {
        letssee<-c(tree[number,1],tree[number,2],tree[number,3],tree[number,4],tree[number,5])  
        print(letssee) 
    } 
    left <- tree[number,1]
    if (!is.na(left)) printtree(tree[left,1]*2,tree)
    right <- tree[number,1]
    if (!is.na(right)) printtree(tree[right,1]*2+1,tree)
}
```

My if condition should be omitting lines when the pick column = 0 but it is still printing and I can't figure out why.

Here's the output:

```
[1] 1 1 0 0 1
[1] 2 1 0 0 1
[1]   4   3 164   0   1
[1] 8 0 0 0 0
[1] 9 0 0 0 0
[1] 5 1 0 0 1
[1]  10   3 208   1   1
[1]  11   3 181   1   1
[1] 3 1 0 0 1
[1] 6 1 0 0 1
[1] 12  3  1  1  1
[1] 13  3 95  0  1
[1]   7   3 159   1   1
[1] 14  0  0  0  0
[1] 15  0  0  0  0
```

Is it ignoring my if statement because of is.na()?  If I don't have the is.na check I get an error for "missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed" so it has to be there.

Comment: Tree data structures are available in the data.tree package and via Rcpp. Are you reinventing that wheel within the confines of a data.frame here?

Comment: I don't think so - the data frame is ordered in a different way than what I need.  So I am re-ordering it in a way that is useful for my purposes.  I can save the new structure in a data frame and omit those rows, but that seems inefficient.  I'm wondering why the condition is being ignored in the output.

Comment: `!is.na(tree[number,5] != 0)` is never going to be `FALSE`, since `pick` is never `FALSE`.. Why are you looking for `NA`s there? Replace with `tree[number,5] != 0`.

Comment: if you omit the !is.na it will kick off the following error: missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Answer (score 0):

If tree[number, 5] happens to really equal zero, then the internal test

```
tree[number, 5] !=0
```

Will return FALSE. FALSE is not an NA value, so !is.na(FALSE) will always return TRUE. So the if statement as you've written it will always return TRUE if tree[number, 5] is zero.

Maybe try:

```
if (!is.na(X) & X !=0) {...}
```

Comment: Thanks Gabriel, this didn't work but I was able to next another if statement 
if (!is.na(tree[number,5] != 0)){
   if (tree[number,5] != 0)
and it works now, however it seems like I should be able to do it in one statement like your suggestion...

Comment: Hmm yeah I suspect there must be a way. Potentially try using && instead of &? && does a lazier evaluation from left to right and will terminate immediately if X is NA. I think the problem with the version I wrote is that NA != 0 evaluates to NA and (TRUE & NA) evaluates to NA which will throw you an error.